# rsync skip non existing files on source

Tags: python, linux, rsync

I'm developing a script in python that could collect logs from multiple machines. I'm using rsync. But there's a problem. I have logs for multiple services that look like:

```
service1.log
service2.log
service3.log
... and so on
```

Paths to this files and folders are specified in code. But sometimes I get in situation when some log files do not exist yet. And rsync does not finish successfully.
How can I skip files that do not exist on source machine?
P.S. I'm using saltstack to rule machines, so I call:

```
__salt__['cmd.retcode']('rsync -a file1 file2...')
```

Comment: maybe best to use a try/except

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there's no exception. I call it like cli utility and it just doesn't return ret_code 0.

Comment: how are you using it? I thought you were maybe using subprocess or pexpect

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, I forgot to include it in my post. I'm using SaltStack. I do __salt__['cmd.retcode']('rsync -a file1 file2..')

Comment: Can you copy the directory instead of individual files?

Comment: @unutbu not for this action. It grabs only specific logs from `logs` folder. It contains many files I don not need at all.

Comment: ah ok I have zero experience with salt, do you pass a single file or a list of files to copy to salt?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham a list. I have about 10 services and need to collect its logs. But sometimes some of them do not write anything to logs, so files just do not exist.

Comment: Can't you verify the existences of your source files before you call rsync, and remove the non-existent ones from your source list?

Comment: @Evert this is the only thought I have. Just was hoping that rsync can handle this.

Comment: what is stopping you from just transferring the files?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, what does `-t` do?

Comment: @oleg.foreigner, there is a `--ignore-non-existing ` flag that may work

Comment: -t is for 'preserve modification times'. Didn't get how it can help.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this flag is for target, not source :(

Comment: It does indeed look like rsync doesn't have an option for this ([similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/303444/how-can-i-get-rsync-to-ignore-missing-files) also don't show an easy solution); probably for the better, because most of the time you want to know that a source file doesn't exist. I think verifying the files exist beforehand will be the way to go (possibly building the filelist using `glob` or `fnmatch` from your initial list, instead of removing entries by verifying the file existence).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `--ignore-missing-args`:

The version 3.1.0 man page says,

> --ignore-missing-args
>
> ```
>  When rsync is first processing the explicitly requested
>  source files (e.g. command-line arguments or --files-from
>  entries), it is normally an error if the file cannot be
>  found.  This option suppresses that error, and does not
>  try to transfer the file.  This does not affect subsequent
>  vanished-file errors if a file was initially found to be
>  present and later is no longer there.
> ```

For example:

```
% rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31
% rsync bogusfile dest
rsync: link_stat "/tmp/bogusfile" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
% rsync --ignore-missing-args bogusfile dest
# <no error>
```

---

The `--ignore-missing-args` option was added some time between version 3.06 and 3.1.0.

The [online version 3.06 rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) does not mention it. But [the git repository](https://mattmccutchen.net/rsync/rsync.git/commitdiff/42d8ec616d5108d1dc2bc949fe967620da653451) indicates this option was added in 2009.

Comment: Thanx! I got 3.0.6 so I didn't find this option in my man pages.

Comment: `--ignore-missing-args` will still show an error when the parent directory of the source file(s) is missing. Eg: `rsync --ignore-missing-args /tmp/bogusfile /newfile` will work because `/tmp/` exists. but `rsync --ignore-missing-args /tmp/bogusdirectory/bogusfile /newfile` will fail with _rsync: change_dir "/tmp/bogusdirectory" failed: No such file or directory (2)_  [with rsync **v. 3.1.2  protocol version 31**]

Comment: The options was added in the version 3.1.0, according to the news file (https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.1.0).